# Fixed padding in contenteditable element

Tags: html, css, textarea, overflow, contenteditable

The padding of a `textarea` is always fixed. When the text content of the textarea is scrolled, the padding remains near the edges.

The padding of a `contenteditable` element behaves differently. When the text content of the element is scrolled, the padding moves with it.

[This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jyuko6gx/) illustrates the difference.

Can a `contenteditable` element by styled so its padding behaves more like `textarea` padding, staying in place while the text content is scrolled?

Comment: Good question. I am also curious if any potential solutions to this could, or should, differentiate between a `contenteditable` element and any other regular block element, because essentially a `contenteditable` element is just behaving like any other block element.

Comment: and `:after` gets scrolled too ... :) why don't you use a `textarea` ? :) at some point, simulating dedicated form elements gets really hairy :)

Comment: It does seem strange at first glance. The difference is that text can't be vertically centered within a `textarea` but can be vertically centered within a `contenteditable` element using `display:flex`. See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jyuko6gx/4/). I need text to be vertically centered, so a `textarea` won't do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your specific question of whether a non-textarea "contenteditable" block level element's padding can behave like a textarea's is "no."

There is likely a way to achieve this look by adding additional elements to your div, but the padding of your div will always behave as padding is designed to.

Your padding issue has nothing to do with the "contenteditable" property. You could take the "cnotenteditable=true" off of your div, and the padding behaves the same way. Padding "clears an area around the content" of the element, which in this example is the text in your div. The padding will always remain around the text, not around the inside of the div.

Answer (score 0):

```css
<style type="text/css">
            contenteditable] {
                outline: 0px solid transparent;
            }
</style>
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="padding:20px">
    <div contenteditable="true"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score -1):

A reply in 2019. Set:

```
border: 10px solid black;
background: black;
color: white;
```

Works perfectly.
fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shill/2k81acux/